# Convert Date to another format

Tags: java, android, date

I have a date :

```
String endDate = "2015-07-22 00:00:00";
```

I construct a formatter for this date :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

But how to convert date to format `yyyy-MM-dd`?
I want to get only `2015-07-22`.

Comment: Use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`?

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way simpler than you'd think.

You can just use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

It ignores everything that doesn't fit the format.

Comment: Yeap. Many Thanks. I will approve at 10 minutes. StackOverflow disallow this to me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = "2015-07-22 00:00:00";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
        String newDateString = dateFormat.format(date1);
        System.out.println(newDateString);
    }
```

**output**

```
2015-07-22
```